# Shell script to find cpu utilization using SAR command and send email if usage is more than 75 percent

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
13:30:01          CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
13:40:01          all      0.56      1.21      0.69      1.64      0.00     95.89
Average:          all      0.63      1.25     11.10      7.48      0.00     79.55
```

Here is the output of sar command. I want to add the %user and %system from the average and if its more than 75 percent send an email to user. please help and also please let me know if there is any better method to calculate cpu usage.

Comment: Sar is used for historical CPU/memory/sway/... usage. If you want to check the current utilization you'd better use `top`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=$' '
USAGE=( $( sar | tail -1 | cut -c20-29,40-49 ) )
IFS=$saveIFS
SUM=0
for (( CNTR=0; CNTR<${#USAGE[@]}; CNTR+=1 )); do
    FLOAT=( $( echo ${USAGE[$CNTR]} | tr ',' '.' ) )
    SUM=( $( echo "$SUM+$FLOAT" |bc  ) )
done
INT=${SUM/.*}
echo $INT
if [[ $INT == "" ]]; then
    INT=0
fi
if [ $INT -ge 75 ]; then
    mail -s "CPU usage is above 75%" mailbox@yourcompany.com < $INT
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to try your script. Meanwhile i am facing issues with the script i have tried. I calculated the idle time for the cpu and if its less than 25 then it would trigger an email for high cpu usage. Below is the script.. error is line 7: integer expression expected.                              #!/bin/bash
#max_idle=25
idletime=$(sar -u 1 1|tail -1|awk '{ print $8}')
echo $idletime;
usage=$(echo  "100-$idletime" |bc)
echo $usage
if [ "$idletime" -lt 25 ]; then
mail -s "CPU usage is above 75%" mail@xxx.com < $
fi

Comment: apologies.. code is not getting properly indentated in the previous post

Comment: bc gives back a float not an integer. If you would like to use bash if to compare it with a value, you have to remove the values from the float which are less then 1. So, if idletime equals 3.04 then you have to remove the .04 part before comparing value to 25. Bash can only compare integer values. So you convert 3.04 to 3 and 3 can be compared with 25. use this:  INT=${idletime/.*} before if. And if syntax should be like this: if [ "$idletime" -lt 25 ]; then echo $usage; fi

Comment: Issue is even if i remove the bc ,usage=$(echo "100-$idletime"), then also the  line- if [ "$idletime" -lt 25 ];  gives me an error  integer expression expected.

Comment: if you echo the $idletime, what do you see. Number like 12.04 or 12,04 ? So with coma or point. You need point for bc as an operation, not comma. If you have comma then you need the tr command to replace it to point.

Comment: 99.44 is the idle time output. there is no comma there

Comment: INT=${SUM/.*}.. This part of your code has solved my issue. It converted the float to int. I have one doubt. what exactly does ${SUM/.*} do. when i echoed the output, i got int part as the output and that solved my issue. I would like to know how it really works. Thanks a lot. this coversion has helped me in making my code work

Comment: It is just remove the part from "." so removes numbers below 1. Bash if can compare only integer, so that's why it is necessary to remove that part. This is similar to a INT function in Basic which takes the integer parts of a number and removes the remaining part. e.g. it converts 1.8 to 1 You can use it for rounding if you add 0.5 to the number before you convert it to integer. e.g if you have 1.4 you add 0.5 to this you get 1.9 and int it will be 1 but if you have 1.5 and add 0.5 to it and int it you will get 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPFILE=/tmp/CPUtmp
sar |awk '$1 == "Average:"{T=$3+$5; if (T > 75){print T}}' > $TMPFILE
if [ -s $TMPFILE ] ; then
  mail -s "CPU usage is above 75%" mailbox@yourcompany.com < $TMPFILE
fi
```

If you want current utilization, "sar 5 6" instead of "sar" will check at 5-second intervals for half a minute.